# How to check only active tab's check boxes? it is checking others also

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have 5 tabs when i am checking **select all** check box on current tab it is checking other tabs rows also.Plz help me.
Below code:

```
$('.group-checkable').click(function() {
  var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox');
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});

  $(document).delegate('.deleteAll', 'click', function() { 
    if($('input[name=credential_id]:checkbox:checked').length>0){
      var check = confirm("Do you wish to continue?");
      if(check){ 
      var credential_ids = new Array(); 
      $('input[name=credential_id]:checkbox:checked').each(function(i){      
          credential_ids[i] = $(this).val();
      });
      $.ajax({
          url: 'credentials/delete',
          type: 'GET',
          datatype:'json',
          data: { credential_ids:credential_ids},
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
        });
      } `enter code here`
    }
    else{
      alert("Sorry..No Record Selected..!");
    }   
  });
```

Comment: Post relevant html structure

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

```
$('.group-checkable').click(function() {                   // when 'group-checkable' is clicked
  var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox');                        //  find ALL checkboxes
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));   //   Set their checked attribute
});
```

You will want to adjust the selector on the 2nd line to be more selective.

Comment: thanks john.. 2nd line checking all check boxes fine.. But how i'll check only current tab's  check boxes?